# How can I get details for each item from an array of objects?

Tags: html, arrays, angular, object, web

I have an array of objects from which I take a name to create a list. When I click on one element of the list, a modal window should open to me in which detailed information about this element will be shown (you need to display a certain object), you can suggest how this can be implemented in Angular ?

Comment: share a snippet of your code otherwise it will be difficult to find a solution for your problme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example, if you are using angular you are going to use *ngFor for array of objects

array of objects
eg:

```
ArrayObjects= [
{
  "id": 1,
  "place": "Sweden"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "place": "USA"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "place": "England"
}
]
```

if you are going to use to show data in table

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th> Sl.No </th>
      <th> Place  </th>
      <th> Popup Action </th>
   </tr>

   <tr *ngFor="let group of ArrayObjects; index as i">
       <td> {{i+1}} </td>
       <td> {{group.place}}  </td>
       <td (click)="ClickMeToGetParticularData(group, i)" > </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

```
In .ts part

ClickMeToGetParticularData(data, index){
    console.log("Required data", data)     ////////// use this to get data to show in popup
    console.log("Required index", index) ///// if you want index
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try with a custom div modal, if you are using none of the ui kits or frameworks.

If you are using kits like material, you can use the material modal to display on clicking that item. To know which data to be passed, you can pass the id of the row data on clicking and then populate the required data from the array using filter().